# output of char ++. Please explain

Tags: c#, .net

Can you please explain why the output of Console.WriteLine(beta) is 'A'?According to me it should be 'B'.

```
public static void Main()
{
    char alpha = 'A';
    char beta = alpha ++;
    char c = alpha++;
    Console.WriteLine(alpha);  //output is C
    Console.WriteLine(beta); //output is A

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/increment-operator

Comment: You should invest in a book

Answer (score 2):

Because you wrote

```
char beta = alpha++;
```

instead of

```
char beta = ++alpha;
```

alpha++ returns the value of alpha (1), then increments alpha.

++alpha increments alpha, then returns the new value.  (2)

Comment: Thanks.. It cleared my doubt. I was confusing it by related with value type .